# Font lock in emacs minor mode

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to build a minor mode to `org-mode` that highlights inline `[todo: <text here> ]` blocks as red and bold (`org-todo` face). But when I run `M-:` and

```
(progn 
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil '("\\[todo:[^\]]*\\]"  . 'org-todo) 'append-keywords)
  (font-lock-flush))
```

The todo elements get the `font-lock-keyword-face` which kind of makes sense in retrospect but by that logic wouldn't one expect there to be a `font-lock-add-` function for each face as well?

Secondarily I have two more questions. a) I noticed this method breaks down when todo items extend to multiple lines. Is there a simple way of mitigating that? b) I can't seem to find a way to undo the effect of `font-lock-add-keywords` when the minor mode is disabled.

Comment: you'll need to do `font-lock-remove-keywords` on disabling the mode... I personally use following for that task: https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-common-hooks.el#L20

Comment: Please pose only one question per question.